# How do I get the state value from the outputted json using the --query flag?

Tags: json, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I ran this awscli command and and im trying to get the value of the 'State' key using --query:

```
ws emr describe-step --profile dev --cluster-id j-12345678 --step-id s-12345678abc
```

output:

```
{
    "Step": {
        "Status": {
            "Timeline": {
                "EndDateTime": 123456.632,
                "CreationDateTime": 1234566.779,
                "StartDateTime": 1623122991201544.588
            },
            "State": "COMPLETED",
            "StateChangeReason": {}
        },
        "Config": {
            "Args": [
                "s3-dist-cp",
                "--s3Endpoint",
                "s3.amazonaws.com",
                "--src",
                "s3://test-bucket/",
                "--dest",
                "s3://test-bucket-2"
            ],
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Properties": {}
        },
        "Id": "s-123456789",
        "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
        "Name": "Command Runner"
    }
}
```

From the output I would like to extract the the value from the 'State' Key. If thats possible can jq be used instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have EMR to test against but using your example this should work:

```
aws emr describe-step --profile dev --cluster-id j-12345678 --step-id s-12345678abc --query 'Step.Status.State'
```

This is an example using ec2 where I know `--query` works:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId'
```

To use `jq` you can do something like this:

```
aws emr describe-step --profile dev --cluster-id j-12345678 --step-id s-12345678abc |jq -r '.Step.Status.State'
```

**References**

[CLI Usage Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html)